# How to replace CreateDerivedCollection with dynamic data

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I have the following code that converts the items from Items collection of wpf TabControl:

```
public IReadOnlyReactiveList<MyType> MyItems => base.Items.OfType<MyType>().CreateDerivedCollection(_ => _);
```

Both `IReadOnlyReactiveList` and `CreateDerivedCollection` extension are marked as obsolete.

```
base.Items collection is of type `ItemCollection`.
```

I don't know how to replace the call to CreateDerivedCollection with dynamic data and to preserve the functionality. `MyItems` list needs to be updated every time then the base Items collection is changed.

Comment: btw not sure the OfType<MyType> would of done what you wanted in the old version. It wouldn't of updated based on base.Items changing since it removed any observability.

Answer (score 2):

This guide goes over how the conversion works https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/

But to summarise.

```
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<MyType> _myItems;
   public MyClass()
   {
      base.Items
         // This makes a IObservable<IChangeSet<T>> which describes the changes
         .ToObservableChangeSet()
         // this will make sure you get the MyType
         .Filter(x => x is MyType)
         // This will convert them into MyType instances.
         .Transform(x => (MyType)x)
         // This is mostly only needed if your source allows multi threading
         .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
         // This will make your _myItems keep in sync with what's done above
         .Bind(out _myItems)
         .Subscribe();
   }

   public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<MyType> MyItems => _myItems;
}
```

Worth a couple things noting.

DynamicData uses .NET types to expose to the outside world, such as `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>` rather than exposing their own types.

`IObservable<IChangeSet<T>>` (and `IObservable<IChangeSet<TKey, TValue>>`) are the two base observables you can create derived based functionality from. `IObservable<IChangeSet>>` indicates what has changed to a collection. The first time you use `ToObservableChangeSet()` it emits the current state of the collection.

`SourceList<T>`, `SourceCache<TKey, TValue>`  are multithreaded aware and optimised to create `IObservable<IChangeSet<T>>` and `IObservable<IChangeSet<TKey, TValue>>`. Generally SourceList/SourceCache are meant to be private to your classes, and you expose using the `Bind()` method. You generate the change sets by using the `Connect()` method on them.

ObservableCollectionExtended is a good single threaded collection where you don't need to do derived based functionality.