# Detect changes in (elements of) a collection bound to a DataGrid to update other collections in WPF (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

## Responsive UI design: `DataGrid` inputs to cause changes automatically (MVVM)

I am trying to create a simple application in which I have a charting tool that accepts collections as series to be plotted. My plan is to have an input `DataGrid` that is bound to a collection which can be populated manually.

Based on the values inside the `DataGrid`, I would then like to simultaneously populate a different collection that represents the [definite integral](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfDefiniteIntegral.aspx) of whatever function is being plotted, in other words a different function that shows the area between the input function and the x-axis.

As the `DataGrid` is updated, I would like to use MVVM to responsively update the chart as well, to display changes in both the input data and the output data.

### A. Application parts (mock-up and structure)

I have created a gist that contains [my implementations so far](https://gist.github.com/JansthcirlU/ad16e71a16ebb6265820a4ca70cfb95b).

#### 1. Main parts

In short, the application has the following components:

- `Coordinate<T, U>` that has an X and Y property (and uses `INotifyPropertyChanged`)
- `ObservableCollection<Coordinate<double, double>>` for plotting purposes
- `NumericalCalculator` for executing numerical methods

#### 2. Converters

In the WPF chatroom, Maverik suggested I could use value converters to let WPF do the heavy lifting, so I have written the following converters:

- `CoordinateSeriesToStringConverter` converts a collection of coordinates to a string where all the coordinates are separated by comma's
- `FunctionToEquallySpacedConverter` attempts to convert a collection of coordinates into a new collection containing some `n` number of equally spaced coordinates
- `FunctionToIntegralConverter` attempts to integrate the input function (collection of coordinates) to its numerical integral between two bounds (currently does not integrate yet, for testing purposes)

### B. My actual question: How can I detect changes in the `DataGrid`'s items source's elements?

I have gone the value converter route, but it turns out that even with `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented on the elements of my bound `ObservableCollection`, those changes do not activate the converters.

I've already gotten a nice answer from `sparedev` with a different approach, which I will likely try out as well, but I'm still curious how I could solve the value converter issue. I'm sure that if I get that sorted out, both options are equally viable.

UPDATE: I've tried sparedev's method, but even with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, manipulating the `DataGrid`'s items from the UI does not raise any new events. Adding new rows or deleting them raises a `CollectionChanged` event, but unfortunately this alone does not let me update the plots responsively yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020256/how-to-replace-createderivedcollection-with-dynamic-data -> https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/ -> SynchronizedCollectionsViewModel

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only allowed to use a few nuget packages, so reactive UI, while promising, is a dead end for me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's register on CollectionChanged event and update result collection, see below.

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
      InputCollection.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
      {
        foreach (var i in e.NewItems)
        {
          var c = i as Coordinate<double, double>;
          ResultCollection.Add(c);
          c.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
        }
      }

      if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
      {
        foreach (var i in e.OldItems)
        {
          var c = i as Coordinate<double, double>;
          ResultCollection.Remove(c);
          c.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
        }
      }
    }

    private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var c = sender as Coordinate<double, double>;
      Console.WriteLine(c.X + " " + c.Y);
    }
```

May be your Coordinate class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
During setting X or Y property PropertyChanged should raised.

```
  public class Coordinate<T, U> : IComparable<Coordinate<T, U>>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    where T : IComparable<T>
    where U : IComparable<U>
  {
    public Coordinate() { }
    public Coordinate(T x, U y)
        => (X, Y) = (x, y);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private T _X;
    public T X
    {
      get => _X;
      set
      {
        if (value.CompareTo(_X) != 0)
        {
          _X = value;
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(X)));
        }
      }
    }

    private U _Y;
    public U Y
    {
      get => _Y;
      set
      {
        if (value.CompareTo(_Y) != 0)
        {
          _Y = value;
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Y)));
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am currently playing around with value converters to update related collections when the input DataGrid detects a change, but I will try this method next! By the way, how could I use this approach to detect changes in the elements of my collection?

Comment: I've added a small update to my question, I've tried this implementation but unfortunately I yet have to find a way to catch the edited coordinate's `PropertyChanged`. I can only detect the items source's `CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: You can extend Items_CollectionChanged function. During update the collection register PropertyChanged event of each item, I updated the example.